# asp.net mvc dynamic render partials

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an asp.net mvc project, I have a request to render html controls dynamically based on the data type from db,
for example:
i have 2 record in db;
id     | type      | value
===========================
1      | charactor | 1    
2      | number    | 2

in the html side, i want generate these 2 controls differently, for the first record i want to generate as input text, and the second record i want to generate as dropdownlist,
so my solution is create 2 partial views, and based on the type, i will use "renderpartial" to  render different partials.
i like to know if there is any better solutions than this one? i found this solution caused slow performance.

Answer (score 0):

you may use editorfor templates.
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html